# How to back to my main file when multiple files opened

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if some value are exist in another files, and if it is to change the overlapping cell in my main file - like adding 1 for each X - but without closing the another file who just opened.

```
Sub ex12()
Dim StdPr As String
Set myrng = Range("B5:P13")

StdPr = Dir("C:\ex12\*.xls")
Do While StdPr <> ""

Workbooks.Open ("C:\ex12\" & StdPr)
  For Each cl In myrng
      If cl.Value = "X" Then
         ' the missing line #
      End If
  Next
     Workbooks(StdPr).Close savechanges:=False
     StdPr = Dir
Loop


 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code always stays in the "main file" - i.e. the workbook in which your code is running. Be careful that your `Range`, as set in your code, **always** refers to your main workbook because it assumes reference to the active workbook at the time it's set. You'll have to re-assign that variable (or another one) to the range in the opened workbook before you can check those cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ex12()

    Dim StdPr As String, wb as workbook
    dim shtMaster as worksheet

    set shtMaster = thisworkbook.sheets("Master")   'for example

    StdPr = Dir("C:\ex12\*.xls")
    Do While StdPr <> ""

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\ex12\" & StdPr)
        For Each cl In wb.worksheets(1).Range("B5:P13").Cells
              If cl.Value = "X" Then
                  with shtMaster.Range(cl.address())
                      .value = .value +1
                  End with   
              End If
        Next
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        StdPr = Dir()
    Loop

 End Sub
```